# I don't understand why my ActionListeners are not working when pressing JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I use action listener and then call it to a class that relays a function. I didn't want to use `implements ActionListener` in the class because it is more complicated to deal with multiple buttons. Can you access a method from an `ActionListener`?

I am also getting a Serializable caution. I'm not sure what that means. I suppressed the warnings and looked it up online, however, I still do not understand it in context. First GUI project, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class GUI extends JFrame{
    public JFrame j;
    public JPanel p;
    public JButton NEW;
    public JButton update;
    public DefaultTableModel model;
    public JTable jt;

    public GUI(){
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(600,400);
        setTitle("Student Record Management System");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JButton NEW = new JButton("Additional Student");
        NEW.setBounds(10,10,20,20);
        NEW.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                NEWpressed();
            }
        });
        p.add(NEW);
        JButton update = new JButton("Update Exam Scores");
        update.setBounds(50,40,20,20);
        update.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                updatepressed();
            }
        });
        p.add(update);
        String [] col = {"Last Name", "First Name", "HKID", "Student ID", "Final Exam Score"};
        String [][] data = {{"Rollins", "Zachary", "1234", "4321", "88"},{"Preston","John", "4321", "1234", "94"}};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
        JTable jt = new JTable(model);
        jt.setEnabled(false);
        jt.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(400,300));
        jt.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        jt.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        jt.setAlignmentY(BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
        JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(jt);
        p.add(jps);
        add(p);
    }
    public void NEWpressed(){
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"col 1", "col 2", "col 3", "col 4", "col 5"});
    }
    public void updatepressed(){
        jt.setEnabled(true);
        p.add(jt);
        add(p);
    }
    public static void main(String args []){
        GUI a = new GUI();
        a.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with your code. Do you get an exception? If so, post the stack trace please.

Comment: `NEW.setBounds(10,10,20,20);` 1) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. ..

Comment: .. 2) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can call methods from your onclicklistener but the problem is in your called method, you are calling

`model.addRow()`

on DefaultTableModel which is not defined yet. Initialize your "model" variable before calling the pressed method.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is you're shadowing your variables...

You define `model` as an instance variable

```
public DefaultTableModel model;
```

But in the constructor you define a local variable of the same name...

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
```

This means that when `NEWpressed` is called, `model` is `null`

You also define `p` and `jt` as a instance variable

```
public JTable jt;
public JPanel p;
```

But in the constructor, you define a local variable of the same name...

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
//...
JTable jt = new JTable(model);
```

Which means when `updatepressed` is pressed `jt` and `p` are `null`

Lose the local definitions and simply instantiate the instance variables within the constructor...

```
public GUI() {
    p = new JPanel();
    //...
    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
    //...
    jt = new JTable(model);
```